How to Access Flask App and SQLAlchemy Database Connection in Flask-APScheduler Child Threads?
I'm using flask_apscheduler to build a web project that controls scheduled tasks. I’ve encountered an issue where these tasks run in child threads, and within these threads, I can't access the Flask app or the SQLAlchemy database connection.
Here's a rough outline of my project:
I'm using a scheduler with a thread pool and SQLAlchemy for persistence. The project provides a web API to add tasks via requests and records essential task information in a separate task information table. Since task information may change frequently and there’s a large amount of it, I don’t pass this data as parameters when registering tasks with the scheduler. Instead, I pass a task UUID, so that when a task is executed, it fetches the task data from the database on demand. The code is similar to this:
def add_task_with_data(task_data):
    logger = get_logger(__name__)

    task_name = task_data.get("task_name")
    interval = task_data.get("task_interval")
    trigger = IntervalTrigger(seconds=interval)
    task_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())

    scheduler.add_job(id=task_uuid, func=execute_task, trigger=trigger, name=task_name, args=[task_uuid])
    logger.info(f"add task： {task_data}")

    task = Task(task_name=task_name,
                task_uuid=task_uuid,
                task_type=task_data.get("task_type"),
                task_interval=interval,
                task_proxy=task_data.get("task_proxy"),
                task_data=json.dumps(task_data["other_data"]))
    db.session.add(task)
    db.session.commit()
    logger.info(f"add task data")

When the task runs, it first queries the database for the task data before executing. However, because the task runs in a child thread, I can't access the main thread’s Flask app or the database connection. My current code is as follows:
def execute_task(task_uuid):
    logger = get_logger(__name__)
    task_object = None
    try:
        logger.info(f"in task function")
        task_result = db.session.query(Task).filter_by(task_uuid=task_uuid).one_or_none()
        if task_result:
            logger.info(f"get task data from dataset： {task_result}")

The error is:
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.

ChatGPT suggested manually creating a Flask app context, but since this is in a child thread with no existing Flask app, using with to create a context manually doesn't really help.
with current_app.app_context():  # don't work

I can think of a few possible solutions, but they’re all quite inelegant, such as:

Creating a new Flask app instance in each thread
Setting up a web API to retrieve task data in the child thread
Using a pipe or similar method to pass the object to the child thread (?)
Does anyone have a better solution? Thank you very much!

